# Returning extra data from HQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, nhibernate, hql

I'm writing an HQL query, in the form of:

```
from a where ... or exists (from b inner join b.c where ...) and ...
```

I get back an entity of type `a` from this query. However, I need to also know whether the `exists` clause came back true or not later on in my code. If this was SQL, I'd tack it onto the select list. However, even if I add to the HQL select clause, so that it becomes:

```
select a, exists (from b inner join b.c where ...) as x from a where ... or x and ...
```

In my code I now have to choose between viewing untyped data, or viewing typed entities of type `a` and throwing away my value `x` that came back with it.

Is there a way to somehow get back typed data *plus* the extra column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here as I see it:

1) Add the additional property as a read-only mapped property to your entity, making use of the `formula` mapping to derive the value using inline sql or a udf.

2) Get only the data you *need* back using a custom hql query and use the `aliastobeanresulttransformer` to project to a strongly-typed dto that includes your fields of interest.

Which route you go is really up to you, but I'd tend to lean towards option #2 so as not to pollute your domain model with unneeded fields.

Comment: I went the `aliastobeanresulttransformer` route. However, I need to use a user type (IUserType) to map one of the columns. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It should work seamlessly; just select the IUserType-dependant property using hql; it should be processed as if you were selecting a regular entity.

Comment: *aliastobeanresulttransformer*! I wish we could ditch some of this crazy terminology in nhibernate.